# Kotlin does not accept the json file I published in c# because it does not have an ssl certificate

Tags: c#, json, kotlin

I'm working on a project but no matter what I did, I couldn't pass this part.
I created the json structure using asp net in c#. I want to send and receive data to android via this json.
However, when I publish the data in json data through githup, it pulls and processes the data in a complex way, but when I open this data through my project that I wrote through visual studio, it says that the ssl certificate is invalid in the json output, it gives the data, but it gives an error in android. Can we cancel the ssl certificate?

```
package com.fth.eticaret_btk.viewModel

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.fth.eticaret_btk.model.Info
import com.fth.eticaret_btk.model.Product
import com.fth.eticaret_btk.service.ProductAPI
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class ProductViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var job : Job? = null
    val productList = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
    val basket = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
    val totalBasket = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val infoList = MutableLiveData<Info>()
    fun downloaddata(){
        println("retrofit önce")
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
          
           .baseUrl("https://192.168.1.44:5001")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(ProductAPI::class.java)
        println( "fonksiyon öncesi")
        job = viewModelScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO) {
          println("getdata öncesi")
            val response = retrofit.getData()
            println( "veri öncesi")

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    println( "fonksiyon çaliti")
                    response.body()?.let {
                        println("verileri esitleme öncesi")
                       infoList.value = it
                        productList.value = it.data
                        println("verileri esitlendi")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I can't extract data from json file on android using asp net with c#

Answer (score 0):

What is the SSL Certificate error?
I don't see how this can anything to do with Kotlin and parsing JSON.

I suggest you should validate the certificate using other methods, e.g.

- open https://192.168.1.44:5001 in a browser
- use a third party tool like `openssl` [How to verify SSL certificates with OpenSSL on Command Line](https://help.yourwebhoster.eu/en/support/solutions/articles/80000949039-how-to-verify-ssl-certificates-with-openssl-on-command-line)

Comment: When I open it through the browser, it says the ssl certificate is invalid.

Comment: Well there you are - the HTTPS blocks getting the content because the certificate is invalid.  If you cannot provide a valid HTTPS certificate, then you will need to configure the HTTP transport to accept the invalid certificate. Retrofit embeds OkHttp to handle the HTTP communication; you'll need to dig into that to override the behaviour.